# How can i convert my time index to do a seasonal_decompose?

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I have a signal data which looks like this in pandas dataframe - df .

```
time  val
0     152
1     152
2     153
.     .
.     .

511 rows
```

The 'time' value is in seconds and 'val' represents amplitude .

```
df.index = Int64Index([  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,
        ...
        501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506, 507, 508, 509, 510],
       dtype='int64', name='time', length=511)
```

**My end goal is to perform a seasonal decomposition on this time-series data , using the**

```
sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose
```

from

```
statsmodels.api
```

which will work well when i resample the 'time' in seconds .

However that needs the 'time' data to be DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex whereas it is in int64.

I am stuck here . Any suggestions would be very helpful .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is:

```
secs = []
for i in range(len(df['val'])):
     secs.append(np.timedelta64(i, 's'))

df['time'] = secs
```

You will end up with this dataframe:

```
     val     time
0    152 00:00:00
1    153 00:00:01
2    154 00:00:02
3    155 00:00:03
4    156 00:00:04
..   ...      ...
143  295 00:02:23
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: can you tell me if i can use this model for ARIMA time series forecasting ?

Comment: I think so. The only thing is that I used a bogus data and the result problem doesn't make any sense.